# Playing around with Etherlink

Tags: testing

We would be interested to play around with Etherlink, is there any documentation already out there on RPCs and how to get access to test tokens?

Comment: I don't think there is any public documentation out yet. Have you signed up for updates on etherlink.com?

Comment: Also see: https://claudebarde.medium.com/how-to-build-a-dapp-on-the-tezos-evm-rollup-319d8fd56236

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Etherlink isn't really deployed yet. However, we've deployed on ghostnet a work-in-progress instance, you can find a "tutorial" on how to use it in this [blog post](https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/evm-tezos-testnet.html). The implementation and the documentation are still in progress, so it's a bit lacking at the moment. But feel free to ask questions in the meantime.

Comment: thanks, I will go through that blog post and start playing with it.